# Present perfect vs Present continuous with period around now

Tags: tense, present-perfect, present-continuous

I know that we can use Present continuous with period around now. For example

> You are working hard today.

but we can also use Present perfect and Present perfect continuous with period around now. For example

> You have been working hard today.

For me it is unclear what is the difference in the meaning between the 1st and the 2nd examples.

Comment: We use Present perfect continuous for the most common situation - addressee recently finished or soon *will* finish working hard. It feels a bit "odd" to use Present continuous *unless* you place heavy stress on ***are*** (indicating some level of "surprise", in earnest or facetiously). Ordinarily you just wouldn't mention someone working hard with no emphasis, like you wouldn't normally say "It's hot" without an ***exclamation mark**!*

Comment: @FumbleFingers thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The present perfect is used to describe a time period *immediately before* the present, possibly (but not necessarily) including the present moment.

Comment: ...so we would say "You have been working hard today" towards the end of the working period, or later in the day after the worker has finished.